# Use only icons for Ubuntu 9.10 gnome menu

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-9.10, gnome-panel

How can I get replace the "applications places system" buttons with just icons?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that would be cool! :)

I don't know how to put icons there, but to put shorter words there (e.g. Apps Locs Sys) is easy: [ubuntuforum/5043898](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5043898&postcount=11)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no way to replace each of them by an icon. But, if you want to replace them all by a single icon, you can do this:

- right-click the menus and select 'Remove from panel'
- right-click the pane and choose 'Add to panel'
- Choose 'Main menu' and click 'Add'

You should get a new icon in your panel that will show the 'Applications' menu and the 'Places' and 'System' menus as sub menus of the main one.